# Data extraction from Power BI

Tags: api, powerbi

I am researching whether its possible to extract data from Power BI into another system via Rest API. Internet is full of articles explaining the data ingestion into power bi but not extraction. Anyone knows whether its possible to do the opposite/can point to some helpful articles, would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using the XML/A endpoint, there's a REST API called [ExecuteQueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries-in-group), which you can call from any programming language, Power Automate, or try online.